# Notes app for Android with tags

Tags: android, project-management, note-taking

I'm looking for a note taking (or tasking) app where I can assign tags to each note (or task) and be able to edit the tags. I also want to be able to attach priorities to each note and sort the notes (all together or within a given tag) based on priority. Having widgets displaying the notes with a given tag would be great.  Something in between Color Notes and Wunderlist.

Wunderlist is not what I'm looking for because its tag editing functionality is rather cumbersome and doesn't support priorities.

Comment: I don't know which notes app supports exactly that, but you might wish to check my [list of notes apps](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_notes).